# Moving files using For Loop in Batch File programming

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to organize files by filetypes.

The idea is to move all files with extensions, *except for the running script*, into new directories, each named with the extension.

What code should I need to add or substitute for some of the code given below? This `.bat` file is in `Documents` folder and there are some files there.

```
@echo off
set x="%cd%\log.txt"
rem 'log.txt' contains the name of folder 'My Folder' and is already created in Downloads folder.
for %%a in (".\*") do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%i In ('type %x%') do (
        if "%%~xa" neq "" if "%%~dpnxa" neq "%~dpnx0" (
            if not exist "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\%%i\%%~xa" md "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\%%i\%%~xa"
            move "%%a" "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\%%i\%%~xa\"
        )
    )
)
pause
```

OUTPUT:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Why do you think you need any modification to your code? Do you have wrong results? Which ones? Error messages? ...

Comment: Your question is unclear.. Please clarify.

Comment: please delete this comment and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55741871/edit) your question with the explanation of your issue.. it is impossible to read the comment like this.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Updated!

Comment: ok, but you just changed code.. what issues are you experiencing? You are not explaining your problem is. I am not really going to try and rebuild your environment on my system just to try and figure out the issue when you can just tell me what your problem is. I need input, current results and expected results. `:)`

Comment: I have the output there, .. My desire is to see the output of the 4th line which should be found in 'My Folder' a sub-directory of Downloads. @GerhardBarnard

Comment: That looks better. Will have a look now when at my pc.

Comment: Suggest you try setting `@echo on` or `echo` some commands to check the printed output. I get no errors with a test. Perhaps `log.txt` is not in current directory, so perhaps it is `type %x%` causing the error.

Comment: @michael is right: only way to reproduce your output is a missing `%x%` file (probably it isn't where you expect it to be. Think about `%cd%` vs. `%~dp0`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create folders as `C:\users\username\Downloads\.ext` including the dot.

```
@echo off 
set "x=%~dp0\log.txt"
rem 'log.txt' contains the name of folder 'My Folder' and is already created in Downloads folder.

  for /F "delims=" %%i In ('type %x%') do (
   if "%%~xi" neq ""  if "%%~fi" neq "%~f0" (
       md "%userprofile%\%%~xi" >nul 2>&1
       move "%%~fi" "%userprofile%\Downloads\%%~xi\"
       )
   ) 
pause
```

If you do not want the dot. i.e `C:\users\username\Downloads\ext`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "x=%~dp0\log.txt"
rem 'log.txt' contains the name of folder 'My Folder' and is already created in Downloads folder.

  for /F "delims=" %%i In ('type %x%') do (
   if "%%~xi" neq ""  if "%%~fi" neq "%~f0" (
       set "ext=%%~xi"
       call set ext=!ext:.=!
       md "%userprofile%\!ext!" >nul 2>&1
       echo move "%%~fi" "%userprofile%\Downloads\!ext!"
       )
   ) 
pause
```

Note, I removed the `%%i` from the `md` command as it will create a folder with the name of the file, if that is what you wanted, just put it back.

Answer (score 0):

Given my understanding of what you're trying to do, I would suggest something a little more like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DestDirName=My Folder"
If Exist "%~dp0log.txt" Set /P "DestDirName="<"%~dp0log.txt"
If Exist "log.txt" Set /P "DestDirName="<"log.txt"
For %%A In (*)Do If /I Not "%%A"=="%~nx0" If Not "%%A"=="log.txt" If Not "%%~xA"=="" (
    Set "FileExtension=%%~xA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    RoboCopy . "%UserProfile%\Downloads\%DestDirName%\!FileExtension:~1!" "%%A" /Mov>Nul
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```

Lines `2`, `3` and `4` will `Set` the name of the parent directory in `Downloads` which will hold the directories for your files to be moved to. I have used a new directory named `My Folder` as a backup just in case the file `log.txt` cannot be found in either the current directory, or that holding your running batch file. It currently selects the name in the following order of preference: 'current directory', 'batch file directory', 'My Folder'; you can switch lines `3` and `4`, if you'd prefer the 'batch file directory' to take precedence over the 'current' directory. If `log.txt` is found, the `Set /P` command will set the variable `DestDirName` to the content of the first line of that file, *please don't use doublequotes or a trailing backslash in that content*.

The `For` loop will then proceed to move all files with extensions to directories named using their extension, *without its leading period*, held within the directory, from lines `2`-`4`, and inside the users `Downloads` directory. When doing that it will not include itself or any file named `log.txt`.

*BTW, it doesn't matter if the directory name string value of `%DestDirName%` already exists in `Downloads`, it will be created automatically if it doesn't*.